# How to I assign OWNER RIGHTS permissions to a file in Windows 7?

Tags: security, windows-7

When I run ICACLS on a file, it returned:

```
foobar.LDF  OWNER RIGHTS:(OI)(CI)(F)
            BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

What securityid do I pass to `icacls` to assign to the generic user "OWNER RIGHTS" ?

Answer (score 0):

At least on Server 2008 R2 this works fine:

```
icacls.exe pack /T /grant "OWNER RIGHTS:(OI)(CI)(F)"
```

Comment: I did this and it didn't complain. But when I run icacls on the file, `OWNER RIGHTS` was not in the list of granted users.